# Delete rows not having data after comma

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file consisting of comma separated pairs, for example:

```
a, 123
b,   456
c,
d,345
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
a, 123
b,   456
d,345
```

Since `c` doesn't have data after the comma, I don't want that line to be displayed. I would like this removal to occur for every line with missing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked for sed, print only lines with a comma followed by a character:

```
sed -n /,./p
```

You could do the same thing with grep, though.

```
grep ,.
```

Comment: Thank you .. Sed worked good for me ..